# Can I update a file via email

Tags: email

I'm looking for a way to update a file (override it if need be) on the SD Card from an email attachment with one click, sort of like a Batch file in windows.

We have 50 tablets at work and every now and then we need to update a price list file. Most of the users are not too bright and can't copy from the attachment and then navigate to the correct folder and then paste the file in.

I would like to know if there is any way to automate this like a batch file in windows, is it even possible.

All tablets are using 4.2.1 and are Asus TF300T and NOT Rooted. I usually email the updated file then have to spend 15 min with EACH person holding their hand to update it. Any help or direction to a thread with something similar would be very appreciative

Comment: TBH, it sounds like you want to replace your email solution with a Dropbox-like app (but not specifically Dropbox, unless you want the whole world to see your price list).

Comment: In default email client, and I believe most other email clients, once you clicked on the attachment, the file will be cached on the device, so it wouldn't need to be redownload (at least until the cache is full). Is there any reasons why you need to put it in a local folder?

Comment: Taking up Dan's suggestion: did you look into [ownCloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OwnCloud)? This would enable you to host the file(s) on your own server, or rent a space with your provider to run the service.

Comment: Hi all It needs to go into a local file so the guys can find it. If it was just to stay in the email program it would get lost with other email the tablet recieves

Comment: A cloud type server is not an option as they only get Wi-Fi for a limited time of the day, so I need it to be stored on the tablet (on the SD card preferably).
It would be something like a bat file on windows, just click on it and it would copy the PDF file that is in the same email as the .bat file and then paste it into the stored folder on either the SD card or if I have to, I can store all the PDF’s on the device’s internal storage.